# Which SDK is good for use Twitter Streaming API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, streaming

I'm using Objective-C for developing iPhone applications,
but I have no idea that which SDK can provide Twitter's streaming API (like receiving new tweets from timeline, notification that someone favorited my tweet, etc.) and OAuth feature.

Is there any SDK for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you really looking for a SDK? You want something like Objective-C classes wrapping the data in the Twitter streaming API?

It is a web service and you don't really need a SDK. Read the documentation at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis and send requests accordingly.

Get acquainted with the networking parts of Cocoa, for example check out this tutorial: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/cocoa-application-driven-by-http-data.html

To parse the JSON data you get from Twitter's API you can use a parser like SBJson: http://stig.github.com/json-framework/

Comment: I didn't know that If I want to use streaming API I should make this as a raw HTTP request call.

Comment: Your implementation should handle the stream. It's not as difficult as it might seem. Check out the docs and play around with it. Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

You could automate your requests based on your requirements.
For integrate `Twitter` in your application refer to these links:

**Overview:**
[iOS Twitter Framework](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios)

**First step to integrate twitter:**
[Adding the Twitter Framework](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/how-add-twitter-framework-your-ios-project)

**Apple Twitter framework docs:**
[Twitter Framework reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html)

**Tweeting Apple sample code:**
[Tweeting](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#samplecode/Tweeting/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011191-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

Comment: Is that really not possible with Twitter's streaming API? https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis

Comment: Good advice, i didn't know this API, and i misunderstood the word "streaming" in ths case :)

Answer (score 0):

A very good Twitter Streaming Framework for iOS 5 with TWRequest : 

https://github.com/stuartkhall/TwitterStreams